# Dificuldade em exibir dados na tela com angular

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Boa tarde pessoal

Estou fazendo um app, onde, ao digitar um texto, a mensagem deve aparecer na tela. Mas algo estranho acontece, apenas os cards (onde o texto deve ser exibido) é que aparece e vazios! Sem o texto.

HTML:

```
ion-view title="Chat" hide-back-button="false">
<ion-content overflow-scroll="true" padding="true" class="has-header">

    <div ng-repeat="mensagem in mensagens">
       {{mensagem.nome}}
       {{mensagem.msg}}
       {{mensagem.hora}}
    </div>

</ion-content>

<form name="chatForm">
 <ion-footer-bar class="bar-stable item-input-inset">
 <!--<button class="button button-clear button-positive button-icon button-camera ion-camera" ng-click="addMedia()"></button>-->
  <label class="item-input-wrapper">
    <input type="text" ng-focus="inputUp()" ng-blur="inputDown()" name="chat" ng-model="mensagem.chat" placeholder="Texto" ng-required="true" ng-disabled="disableButtonChat"/>
  </label>
  <!--<button class="button-mic ion-ios-mic"></button>-->
  <button class="button button-clear button-positive" ng-disabled="chatForm.chat.$invalid || disableButtonChat" ng-click="enviarMsgChat(mensagem)">Enviar</button>

  </ion-footer-bar>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
.controller('chatCtrl', function($scope, $http, $window, $ionicScrollDelegate) {
$scope.mensagens = [];
$scope.mensagem = {
  chat: ""
}

$scope.enviarMsgChat = function (mensagem) {
    var msg = mensagem.chat;

    $scope.disableButtonChat = true;

    var dia = moment().format(); //2016-02-16 T 16:05:52-02:00
    var diaP = dia.split('T');
    var dia = diaP[0];

    var horaP = diaP[1];
    var horaP2 = horaP.split(':');
    var hora = horaP2[0]+':'+horaP2[1];

    var idUsuario = $window.localStorage.getItem('idUsuario');
    var nome = $window.localStorage.getItem('nome');
    var usuario = $window.localStorage.getItem('usuario');
    var logradouro = $window.localStorage.getItem('logradouro');

    var msgChat = {
        idUsuario: idUsuario,
        nome: nome,
        usuario: usuario,
        logradouro: logradouro,
        mensagem: msg,
        dia: dia,
        hora: hora
    }

    $scope.mensagens.push({usuario:usuario, mensagem:msg, hora:hora})

}

})
```

Comment: Tenta colocar um `{{mensagens}}` no seu html e veja se o array é exibido na tela.

Comment: O "ImageController" vc está usando? Embaixo do seu form e embaixo da div "card" deixa "{{mensagens}}" para ver se altera o valor quando preenche algum input

Comment: É, realmente tem um controller estranho ali haha

Comment: É esse ImagemController eu nem lembro o pq coloquei ali kkkkk
Mas vou tirar e fazer o teste que sugeriste.

Comment: Coloquei o {{mensagens}} logo abaixo de "<div class="card" ng-repeat="mensagem in mensagens">" e apareceram, 3 vezes isso: {nome: "Flávia Schneider", mensagem: "Olá", hora: "17:32"}

Comment: Por ter um objeto já chamado "mensagem" tente fazer o loop com ng-repeat="mens in mensagens" e na hora de escrever vc chama {{mens.nome}}

Comment: Não @AndréVicente, não funcionou
Como colocando só {{mensagem}} o nome a mensagem e a hora aparecem, tentei fazer o normal:
{{mensagem.nome}}, mas dai não aparece... To achando estranho isso.

Comment: Estranho mesmo. Vendo a imagem que vc postou da para ver que repete 3 vezes mostrando  que tem 3 registros mesmo. Uma outra coisa que tentaria era inspecionar o elemento e ver se o "<h2>" e "<p>" estão realmente vazios

Comment: Cara, refiz parte do código, com base num vídeo de to dos que um cara fez e deu certo. Só que tirei a div que faz aparecer em 3 partes... Vou postar o que refiz

Comment: Acabei de editar os códigos do meu post.

Comment: @AndréVicente, estou conseguindo fazer a mensagem aparecer na tela, PORÉM, se eu digitar outra mensagem, some a última e aparece a nova, ou seja, as mensagens ficam sendo substuidas! Precido que elas "se acumulem"

Comment: Da forma que está no código vc está substituindo o array mensagens pela última mensagem que veio. Vc tem que dar um push no array. $scope.mensagens.push(novoArray).

Comment: Oi @AndréVicente. Sim eu já fiz isso. Ontem mesmo eu encontrei o problema.
Essa parte "$scope.mensagens = [];" tinha que ficar no início do controller e essa $scope.mensagens.push({usuario:usuario, mensagem:msg, hora:hora}) dentro da function que envia.
Vou postar o código atualizado

Comment: Era isso mesmo, blz. Que bom que resolveu. Boa sorte ai.